# Getting NULL value in ASP .net POST controller method from Axios POST request

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, axios

I want to store data via POST method using react axios into table via ASP .net. The API works on postman but the data Im sending on the frontend side shows null on the backend POST method.

React code:

```
var headers = { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('tk'), 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
axios.post("https://localhost:8000/api/" + 'Author',
    {
        Data: this.state.books, //"Book1 (string)"
        Text: this.state.text, //"Douglas M (string)"
        List: [1,2,3] //array
    }, {headers: headers})
    .then((response) => {
        window.location.href = '/home';
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

C# code:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Author value)
    {
        Author input = new Author ()
        {
            Data = value.Data,
            Text = value.Text,
            Lis  = value.List,
            Date = Datetime.now
        };
        _model.Author.Add(input);
        _model.SaveChanges();
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Author model design:

```
public class Author
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Lis { get; set; } //storing list as string in table
}
```

Error returned:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

When the API is executed, the value that the POST method retrieves is NULL. What's the reason for this? I tried using JSON.stringify() for the data in frontend but it didnt work.

Comment: Data needs to be `JSON.stringify()` and your model `Author` and its properties (name and type) from server need to match exactly the object sent from client.

Comment: @Codingwiz yes, I did use JSON.stringify() and ensured that the name and type from server matches the object. Do I need to change the function parameter from Class type to string instead since it's JSON stringify coming in as request?

Comment: Hi @retro_coder, did you use `console.log(this.state.books)` to check if the two value you pass actually have the value? And how is the two properties type, simple string? Pls share the model design of `Author` and also pls share what is the data you post.

Comment: @Rena, added them in, do check it out, thanks

Comment: Hi @retro_coder, you post an array to the string type, of course your backend will receive the null model. One way is that you can change the `string List` to `List<int> List`. The other way is that you can change `[1,2,3]` to `"[1,2,3]"`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Rena, the problem lies with your model not being able to parse array sent from client side to a string. You need to change your `Lis` property to an array so that corresponding properties and their types sent match your model properties and their types.

```
public class Author
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int[] Lis { get; set; } // <-- change from string to array of numbers (since you're sending an array that contains numbers)
}
```

Also `Lis  = value.List` will not work with the Database. You should have a model for `Client-Server` communication and a separate model for your `EF Core DbContext`. Then do a conversion from one model to the other and vice-versa. Automapper can be usefull too.

```
Lis  = string.Join(", ", value.List)
```